# Is 1-d Brownian filtration rich enough to admit a 2-d Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $B_t$ be the standard 1-d Brownian motion, and let $\mathcal F^B_t$ be the induced filtration. Is it possible to construct a 2-d Brownian motion adapted to $\mathcal F^B_t$?

[EDIT] Come to think of it, I guess it is doable. By picking different segments of 1-d path, shifting and scaling, we can construct 2-d Brownian motion out of the 1-d Brownian motion. So, let's make it more challenging:

Is it possible to construct a 2-d Browning motion $(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)})$ which is adapted to $(\mathcal F^B_t)$, and $\mathcal F_t^{(B^{(1)}, B^{(2)})}=\mathcal F^B_t$ for all $t$.

Comment: Before "mak(ing) it more challenging", you might want to explain much more precisely how you came to "guess (the first version) is doable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part is impossible.

Let $B_t$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion with natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$.  Suppose that there is a process $(W_t^{(1)}, W_t^{(2)})$ which is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$.  (This would certainly be true if $(W_t^{(1)}, W_t^{(2)})$ were a Brownian motion whose natural filtration was equal to $\mathcal{F}_t$.)

In particular, $(W_t^{(1)}, W_t^{(2)})$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$.  By the [martingale representation theorem](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/the-martingale-representation-theorem/), there are predictable $B_t$-integrable processes $\sigma^{(1)}_t, \sigma^{(2)}_t$ such that $W_t^{(i)} = \int_0^t \sigma^{(i)}_s\,dB_s$ for $i=1,2$.

Now by considering quadratic variation we have
$$t = [W^{(i)}]_t = \int_0^t \left|\sigma_t^{(i)}\right|^2\,dt \quad \forall t \ge 0, \text{ a.s.}$$
which by the fundamental theorem of calculus implies
$$\left|\sigma_t^{(i)}\right| = 1 \quad \forall t \ge 0, \text{ a.s.} \tag{1}$$
But by considering quadratic covariation we have
$$0 = [W^{(1)}, W^{(2)}]_t = \int_0^t \sigma_t^{(1)}\sigma_t^{(2)}\,dt \quad \forall t \ge 0, \text{ a.s.}$$
and thus
$$\sigma_t^{(1)}\sigma_t^{(2)} = 0 \quad \forall t \ge 0, \text{ a.s.} \tag{2}$$
Now (1) and (2) are contradictory.

Note: I previously thought this argument contradicted the first part too.  The error was that if we just know that $W_t$ is a Brownian motion which is adapted to a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, it does not follow that it is a Brownian motion, or even a martingale, with respect to that filtration.  The obvious counterexample is $W_t = \sqrt{2} B_{t/2}$.

Comment: Beautiful! I tried to find a more elementary approach, but it seems we have to bring out such a big gun like martingale representation theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea for the first part.

In the canonical space, let $B_{[t_1\ t_2]}$
represent a sample path between $[t_1\ t_2]$. We divide
$B_{[0\ \infty)}$ into segments: $B_{[2^{-(n+1)}\ 2^{-n}]}$, for
  $n=...,2,1,0,-1,-2,...$. Now, let's
remove all the segments with $n$ being odd, and use the remaining
segments to construct another path $W_{[0\ \infty)}$ -- and by similar
  construction, we can use the ``removed'' segments to construct yet
  another path (the second component of the 2-d Brownian motion)

First step: we scale (both in time and value) each remaining segment
$B_{[2^{-(2k+1)}\ 2^{-2k}]}$ to fill up the hole between $2^{-2k}$ and
$2^{-2k+1}$, and define for $t\in (2^{-(2k+1)}, 2^{-2k+1})$ for any
integer $k$ ($k$ can be negative).

$W(t) = \sqrt{3} B(2^{-(2k+1)} + \frac{t-{2^{-(2k+1)}}}{3})$

Now, to make the paths continous at the end points, we define for
$t\in (2^{-(2k+1)}, 2^{-2k+1}]$,

$\tilde W(t) = W(t) + \sum_{i=k}^\infty \left [ W_+(2^{-(2i+1)}) -
  W_-(2^{-(2i+1)}) \right ] $

I believe such constructed $\tilde W(t)$ is a Brownian motion, which is
adpated to $(\mathcal F^{B}_t)$, and should be independent of the
second component (constructed using the ``removed segments'').

There are still some details to be figured out around the convergency of 
 $\sum_{i=k}^\infty \left [ W_+(2^{-(2i+1)}) -
  W_-(2^{-(2i+1)})\right ]$. 
I think we can prove the convergency using the iterated logrithm
theorem.

Comment: I was thinking of something along the same lines.  I don't think $[2^{-(n+1)}\,2^n]$ is what you want, exactly.  And you have a problem in that you will find that your second component, which uses the "second half" of these small intervals, will not be adapted.  But as you let the size of the intervals tend to 0, this problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks, Nate, fixed that typo. About your comment on the second component, I don't see the problem yet. When we extend a segment, we always extend to cover the "hole" on the right hand side, that should make the constructed process adapted. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking of something different.

Comment: If we make the segments smaller and smaller (using base 4 instead of 2, then 8, then 16...), I think we can achieve the second part too. But we need to think of the convergency. Surely, it is not global unform. How about "locally uniform"? I mean, uniform between $[0, \   t]$, for any t.

Comment: No, I don't think the idea above for part 2 works.... help!

Comment: As for the convergence of the sum, if I have understood correctly, I think it equals something like $\sum_k (B(2^{-2k}) - B(2^{-(2k+1)}))$.  This is a sum of independent random variables whose variances are $2^{-(2k+1)}$, which is a summable sequence.  By Kolmogorov's convergence criterion, the sum converges almost surely.

Comment: Incidentally, I think it might be possible to perform essentially the same construction in a fancier way: consider the stochastic integrals of two integrands with disjoint supports.  These should be independent time-changed Brownian motions.  Now if you invert the time change, you'll get Brownian motions back, and it should be possible to do this so that the inverse of the time change doesn't "look into the future".

Comment: @NateEldredge I am very curious if this problem has been resolved or not. It's not obvious why the construction is a Brownian motion. I would also like to know if one can construct a Brownian motion $W$ from $B$ such that it is adapted to $\mathcal F^B$ and is independent of $B$. I have related question which is posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020801/brownian-motions-under-different-filtrations-quadratic-covariation-covergence